# How to disable/remove specific OpenSSL crypto algorithms from OpenSSL source code?

Tags: c, openssl

How can I add/create a c/c++ OpenSSL static library with specific crypto algorithms? Let's say I don't want **md5** implementation. how do I create a library without md5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In configure script you can specify `no-<cipher>` option, it will build openssl without the cipher that you specified, you can refer to INSTALL file from openssl package

```
  no-<cipher>   Build without the specified cipher (bf, cast, des, dh, dsa,
                hmac, md2, md5, mdc2, rc2, rc4, rc5, rsa, sha).
                The crypto/<cipher> directory can be removed after running
                "make depend".
```

Comment: Does it reduce the size of compiled library?

Comment: I think so as its going to skip code for the ciphers